# Q: Cluster Point Definition Clarificaiton

Tags: calculus, limits

Definition: A real number c is a cluster point of a sequence s iff for every $\epsilon$ > 0 and every natural number N there is some natural number n > N such that $|s_n - c| < \epsilon$.

I am working through Donald Hight's *A Concept of Limits*.

I understand that a sequence such as $(-1)^n \frac{n-1}{n}$ has two cluster points namely 1 and -1. Intuitively, I can see the domain of this sequence creating two equivalence classes defined by the even or odd nature of n which then support the definition to define the appropriate value for c. Then, each equivalence class converges to the associated cluster point.

What I do not understand is how "every natural number N" may be used for both cluster points 1 and -1 for this given sequence or for that matter other sequences with more than one cluster point. I am nagged that values for N that work for c = 1 will conflict with values for N that work for c = -1.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that what is close to $c$ is $s_n$, ***not*** $s_N$.

The definition means that we can find *arbitrarily high* $n$ with the desired property.
The way we translate this into 'math speak' is by saying that, whatever the value of $N$ is, we can always find some larger $n$ with the desired property.

Comment: I infer from this that if we know the cluster point c that the relationship between n and N shall hold as $|s_n -c| < \epsilon$ as long as n > N. I suppose my confusion is how to find c using the definition of a cluster point when the sequence has two cluster points as in the sequence $(-1)^n \frac{n-1}{n}$.

Comment: No, you're reading it wrong. As you wrote it $($"as long as $n>N$"$)$ would be the definition of *limit*. This would mean that, from $N$ onwards, the sequence $s_n$ would always remain at most $\epsilon$-away from $c$. The cluster point definition only requires that some $n>N$ (for which the relation holds) exist, ie, at least one such $n$.